# I have a problem with the android internal memory allocation is permanent

Tags: internal-storage, ram

Has the android "internal memory allocation freeze" been solved?

Example: GS3 internal memory full with photos (picassa sync issue). After moving problem photos to SD card, the internal memory is still an issue due to the fact that internal memory used for the photos remains allocated.

Samsung's answer was to do a hard factory reset (LOL)

Comment: Have you done a hard reboot? Switch off, battery pull, reboot? Worth a look in. There's no fix in KitKat on the S4 or S4 google edition anyway, but a hard boot seems to work intermittantly for me.

Comment: No, reboot didn't work but hard factory reset did. The problem with the reset is that when I restored from the back-up all the app settings are gone which is a very big pain (not a real fix). Does anyone know how to do a back-up whuch includes app settings.

Comment: I can't believe that a lot of users don't seem to think that the allocation "lock-out" is a big problem. Personally I think it is a fundemental fault and if I can't find a way around this I will never buy another android phone again!